# how to set httpheaders in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, internet-explorer, caching, http-headers

I need to set http header for disabling ie (7-8) caching (it disturbs my ajax functionallity).
I've tried inserting this code to the head of my site.master with no result -

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma"
CONTENT="no-cache"> <META
 HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

How and where can I set the HTTP headers?
or do you have a better solution for the ie caching issue.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

This attribute, placed in controller class, disables caching. Since I don't need caching in my application, I placed it in my BaseController class:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
```

Here is nice description about OutputCacheAttribute: [Improving Performance with Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-15-cs.asp)